# Resize calculated window height of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a sticky nav on scroll for a clients website and have got it working. However, because the div above it has a variable height based on the height of the browser window minus the nav for a carousel `height: calc(100vh - 100px);` it's breaking when the browser window is resized. So can someone help me to add a resize event onto the below code, so that it updates the height of the window on resizing the browser?

```
var yourNavigation = $(".home-navbar");
  stickyDiv = "sticky";
  yourHeader = $('.home-carousel').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > yourHeader ) {
    yourNavigation.addClass(stickyDiv);
    $( "#sticky" ).addClass( "sticky__padding" );
  } else {
    yourNavigation.removeClass(stickyDiv);
    $( "#sticky" ).removeClass( "sticky__padding" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to make the `scrollTop` check into a function and call it on `load`, `scroll`, and `resize` If so, you can use either pure JS or jQuery to accomplish this:

```
function headerStuff() {
  var yourNavigation = $(".home-navbar");
  var stickyDiv = "sticky";
  var yourHeader = $('.home-carousel').height();
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > yourHeader ) {
    yourNavigation.addClass(stickyDiv);
    $( "#sticky" ).addClass( "sticky__padding" );
  } else {
    yourNavigation.removeClass(stickyDiv);
    $( "#sticky" ).removeClass( "sticky__padding" );
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", headerStuff);
window.addEventListener("resize", headerStuff);
window.addEventListener("scroll", headerStuff);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Still working on my js skills. So appreciate the help